# Trying to install a file (xf86-input-mtrack) downloaded from Github

Tags: software-installation

I'm quite new to Ubuntu/Linux in general, I'm a mac user and have been able to double click/drag applications to install them.

I've recently been trying to set up some functionality on my Ubunutu 18.04 installed on my mac, and what a saga.

Read the readme, which says, use `./configure` and `make && makefile`.
I've just extracted it on my download folder... I searched on how to install something from Github, and there's no generic answer.

1. My question is, how can I install this thing and get it onto my computer? 
   https://github.com/p2rkw/xf86-input-mtrack#TapDragEnable
2. which file am I supposed to `make` and `makefile`? Am I supposed to use a variable after make or just type make when I'm in the directory?

----------additional details---------

I have gone into `./configure` and `./configure --help`. The readme file says, the next step is to use `make` && `makefile`. I've type those commands in and a few more, but nothing happens.

I tried other `./configure` commands e.g. `./configure install-sh`, `install-sh` and this appears:

```
configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking build system type... Invalid configuration `CC': machine `CC' not recognized
configure: error: /bin/bash ./config.sub CC failed
```

Comment: You are installing from source, a process that hasn't changed in the last three+ decades.  The configure step learns what you are using (including mac osx, gnu/linux, unix..) setting up the following steps.  Make is the 'compile' step...   Generally you read the README or INSTALL file for instructions.  The steps are not machine specific intentionally, making them work if you want to use them on a mac (osx), unix machine (bsd), or gnu/linux (ubuntu or other distro).  Text files (readme etc) provide more specific clues

Comment: the `make` can also understood by a 1980s DOS machine, or windoze (providing build utilities are included).   The configure step however won't recognize a non-nix machine though (so the make won't be as successful there possibly)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm using a mac, running ubuntu for the first time. Mac has made me used to things that "just works", buggers. Turned me soft.

Comment: For clarity, the difference compared to what you're used to is not Mac vs Linux - it's installing ready-made software from ready-made installer vs building something and installing it from source. It would be just as difficult on a Mac - you've just never done it!  Installing nicely packaged stuff on Linux is also super easy.

Comment: To properly format a block of terminal output, paste the text, select the text, and press the `{}` button in the editor (or press Ctrl-K).

Comment: Sweet. cleared it up abit. 
Yea I've never been able to figure out how to self compile when I'm in mac too. I took abit of CS50, but this is a different beast, configuring settings without GUI is challenging. Maybe one day I'll get there.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve here? After wrestling with it for more than half an hour, I managed to compile the source code for the 0.5.0 release, but I couldn't help noticing there is a `xserver-xorg-input-mtrack_0.5.0_amd64.deb` for that release... if you downloaded that file, you could probably install it with a double click.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you'd like to save some effort and have the convenience of the APT package manager supporting you, [`xf86-input-mtrack` is provided in Ubuntu's standard `universe` repository through the package `xserver-xorg-input-mtrack`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=xserver-xorg-input-mtrack&searchon=names).

Note that, except for Ubuntu 14.04, version 0.3.1 is provided, which is somewhat older than 0.5.0 at your Github link. Here's [the Github readme for version 0.3.1](https://github.com/p2rkw/xf86-input-mtrack/tree/eb94a0531f08aca2a932e37678595355b2afcdf1#readme), where you can see that `TapDragEnable` is still included, if you needed that in particular.

To install it:

1. Open a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).
2. Run the following:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-mtrack
   ```
3. Reboot.

Comment: did this, might have dones something right.. cause my track pad doesn't work anymore after a reboot. lol...  I'm searching for the app and can't seem to find the "mtrack" or "xorg"..

Comment: The settings for it should be located in the file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-mtrack.conf`. You'll need to edit it with something like `sudo nano`. You can see the possibilities for options in [the `Configuration` section of the 0.3.1 readme](https://github.com/p2rkw/xf86-input-mtrack/tree/eb94a0531f08aca2a932e37678595355b2afcdf1#configuration). If all else fails, you can uninstall with `sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-input-mtrack` and a reboot.

Comment: Oh, and I think you'll need to reboot after saving any changes to the file to see the effects.

Comment: Thanks @Chai T.Rex , you've been amazingly generous with your knowledge but i've gone in with `sudo nano` to edit the file to `Section "InputClass"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    Identifier      "Touchpads"
    Driver          "mtrack"
EndSection` for a minimal configuration and my trackpad still wouldn't move unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by other answers: If you are solely interested in getting the software installed, using a package manager like `apt` is the easiest way to go.

But as this does not answer the question of how to get the software installed from a Github download, I want to clarify a possible misunderstanding and outline the most common steps to install software from Github.

It is important to note that Github is primarily hosting source code repositories. This means that what you get by clicking on the download button of a Github repository is not an executable program or installer, but the source code of the program. Some repositories provide pre-built executables at the "releases" page of the repository. You can reach this page by clicking on the "releases" label of the respective Github repository page. Pre-built executables of `xf86-input-mtrack` for example can be found here: https://github.com/p2rkw/xf86-input-mtrack/releases

As Github can host any kind of software (and even non-software), the ways to install applications hosted on Github vary wildly. This is the reason why there are no generic instructions on how to install software from Github.

The program you want to install is written in the programming language C. C source code is almost always intended to be compiled into an executable binary file before it can be installed. The `README` document refers to this procedure with the term "Building". This is why this document gives you instructions on how to build as well as how to install your program.

The commands `.configure`, `make`, `make install` are common steps to build and install a program written in C. Most installation guides implicitly assume that you know where and under what circumstances you need to enter these commands, which sadly is discouraging for beginners. These are the steps you have to take *before* you can follow the instructions in the `README`:

1. Open the terminal. It will provide you with a command line where you can enter commands
2. Type in `cd /path/to/your/download`, but substitute `/path/to/your/download` with the actual path to the folder with the source code you downloaded. Hit enter to execute the command. By pointing your computer to this directory you let it know, that the following commands to build and install shall be applied there.
3. Now follow the instructions outlined in the `README`.

Comment: There's some good information in this answer, but "follow the instructions in the README" is really insufficient here.

Answer (score 2):

Before you do anything else, please do the following

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

and then clone the repository, like so

```
git clone https://github.com/p2rkw/xf86-input-mtrack.git
```

if there is a new version available you can update easily like so (inside the folder)

```
git pull
```

Now let's see. You will need developer packages to get there. Unfortunately this is not mentioned in the description.

If you didn't install `build-essential` and I'd guess `gcc` (looks like it but then again I'm an admin not a dev), do so now. Also it's looking for gawk. I hope that's it, might be another package or lib. Didn't have the time to read all of it.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential gcc autoconf gawk pkgconfig
```

You also need at least these packages which are difficult to identify from the errors:

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-dev x11proto-core-dev x11proto-input-dev libmtdev-dev
```

This may be insufficient. It depends on your setup.

Go to the folder which you "gitted" above and then again try.

```
./configure
```

If `./configure` outputs errors, as a general rule of thumb, when you get an error like `no package thingy found`, you can try running `apt search thingy` and see if there is something like `libthingy-dev`, which is probably what you need. If not, I hate to say this, but, put the error into a search engine, and see if someone has trod the path before you...

When it exits successfully, you can run

```
make
```

if it outputs errors, follow the same procedure as for `./configure`, and afterwards run

```
make clean
./configure
make
```

and when that exits successfully, you can run

```
sudo make install
```

Addtional information. If you would like to have a .deb package set the mentioned prefix and execute the package builder like so.

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
dpkg-buildpackage
```

Answer (score 0):

You are downloading the source of a program and building it yourself. This is a very different concept to clicking on an installer.

It doesn't matter where you unpack the source (in most cases). You're not "installing" it there, just putting it somewhere you can build it.

You just do what it says. Type those commands, exactly as written in the readme. If it doesn't work, please edit your post stating what goes wrong.

Comment: ok, thanks for that. Now I'm just trying to get the software running in my system. I've done abit of trial and error but doesn't seem to be going anywhere..

Comment: I note from your edit that you've mistyped the instructions three times now so I suspect you're mistyping it elsewhere too. It's `make && make install`, not `makefile`.

Comment: thanks @Mark Smith , the command `make && make install` returns `make && makeinstall
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.` :(

Comment: Your question is getting a bit cluttered, and doesn't mention any problems fron running `configure`. Just that - don't add any parameters, just run it. Again, if it doesn't work, show us the output. If it does, the make steps should also work.

Comment: have cleared up the other bits so if any other folks might have a chance of helping. Thanks Mark Smith.

Comment: What do you mean by having "gone in" to configure? You execute it. And when you run make, nothing happens? Literally nothing? It just behaves as if you hadn't typed it?

Comment: Compiling is hard. Please try compiling this yourself and give specific instructions. +1 to your comment on the question though